# How to count digits after the decimal point with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

What do I have to change in the following code, so that the amount of digits after the decimal point is shown below the number?

```js
var operator = ['/'];

function F1() {

  answer = document.getElementById("answer");
  digits = document.getElementById("digits after decimal point");
  rZ1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
  rZ2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  op = operator[Math.floor(Math.random() * 1)];

  var a = parseFloat(eval(rZ1 + op + rZ2).toFixed(3));
  var d = 3

  if (a.toFixed(2) == a) {
    a = parseFloat(a.toFixed(2));
    var d = 2;
    if (a.toFixed(1) == a) {
      a = parseFloat(a.toFixed(1));
      var d = 1;
    }
  }

  answer.innerHTML = a;
  digits.innerHTML = d;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="F1()"> New </button>
<p> <label id="answer"> </label> </p>
<label id="digits after decimal point"> </label>
```

Comment: To get the number of decimal digits, you can do something like: `let decimalLenght = (number) => String(number).split('.')[1].length`

Comment: The id of the second label is not spelled the same way ("the")

Comment: As an aside, please don't use global variables--always use `const` or `let`, compare with `===` and save a lot of time and pain.

Comment: Usage: `decimalLength(5.32) // result: 2`

Comment: Thx, the question is answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just locate where the decimal point is with `indexOf`

```js
var operator = ['/'];

function F1() {

  answer = document.getElementById("answer");
  digits = document.getElementById("digits after decimal point");
  rZ1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
  rZ2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  op = operator[Math.floor(Math.random() * 1)];

  var a = parseFloat(eval(rZ1 + op + rZ2).toFixed(3));
  var d = Math.max(0, (a+"").length - (a+".").indexOf(".") - 1);
  answer.textContent = a;
  digits.textContent = d;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="F1()"> New </button>
<p> <label id="answer"> </label> </p>
<label id="digits after decimal point"> </label>
```